# How do I add a view controller that already has a parent controller as a child of another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, mobile-development

I have 3 view controllers.

ViewcontrollerA is child of ViewcontrollerB

I want to add ViewControllerB as a child of ViewcontrollerC.

Inside ViewcontrollerC.m

```
ViewcontrollerC.view = ViewcontrollerB.view;

[self addChildViewController:ViewcontrollerB];

[self.view addSubview:ViewcontrollerB.view];

[ViewcontrollerB didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

It gives me this error Thread 1:
Exception: "child view controller:<ViewcontrollerA: 0x7fee59454a60> should have parent view controller:<ViewcontrollerC: 0x7fee5962f670> but actual parent is:<ViewcontrollerB: 0x7fee694510f0>"

Comment: `ViewcontrollerC.view = ViewcontrollerB.view;`? What is `ViewControllerC`? What is `self`? `ViewControllerD`?

Comment: Self is ViewControllerC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ViewcontrollerB.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview: ViewcontrollerB.view];
[self addChildViewController: ViewcontrollerB];
[ViewcontrollerB didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

You are missing this line: `ViewcontrollerB.view.frame = self.view.bounds;`